# Python: Continuous addition to a 3d scene in a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, mayavi, mplot3d, mayavi.mlab

Can you give example code to

1. initially draw a surface
2. then draw some random lines in a loop. Between drawing each line, a little time is wasted, to give the impression of an animation.

The code should work both from `ipython` and `pydev`.

Comment: Can you reduce this down to an example we can test?  This looks correct at first glance, but there are too many things that I have to guess at to even try to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @tcaswell I posted a full script as you see. In mlab albeit. But I still would enjoy mplot3d version.

Answer (score 1):

One answer using the `mayavi` is below:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
import time
from tvtk.tools import visual


# # prepare surface data
rng = 20
step = 1
X = np.arange(0, rng, step)
Y = X
Z = np.random.uniform(-1, 0, (rng, rng))

# # draw the surface
fig = mlab.figure(size=(500, 500), bgcolor=(1, 1, 1))
visual.set_viewer(fig)
s = mlab.surf(X, Y, Z)
mlab.axes(color=(0, 0, 0))
mlab.view(40, 40)
mlab.outline()

for i in xrange(5):
    # # sleep a little to give the impression of animation
    time.sleep(1)
    # # get coordinates of two random points
    p1 = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (3,)) 
    p2 = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (3,))
    line = np.vstack((p1, p2))
    x, y, z = (line[:, dim] for dim in xrange(3))

    # # connect points
    mlab.plot3d(x, y, z, figure=fig, tube_radius=.05, colormap='Greens')

mlab.show()
```